# C++ Iterators operations

Tags: c++, iterator

Please check the commented line of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
    vector<int>numbers{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    vector<int>::iterator it, beg=numbers.begin(), end=numbers.end();

    for(it=beg; it!=end; it++){
        cout<<*it++<<endl; //THIS LINE PRINTS 1 3 5 7
    }

  return 0;
}
```

I'm reading about iterators and trying some things. That line seems to print the element `it` refers to, then increment `it`. In fact it produces the same results as:

```
  cout<<*it<<endl;
  it++;
```

I didn't explain it clearly, the real question is: can you perform 2 operations on an iterator like that?

And why `*(it+1)` is different than `*(it++)`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're increasing your iterator twice. Once in the for loop "*header*" itself:

```
for(it=beg; it!=end; it++){
```

and once inside the loop

```
cout<<*it++<<endl;
```

and thus you are skipping elements. The second line should be:

```
cout<<*it<<endl;
```

Also, *(it++) is not the same as *(it+1) because the postfix operator ++ returns the original value (whereas prefix returns the incremented value). More importantly, *(it+1) doesn't actually increment the iterator, where using ++ does. Let's illustrate with an example:

If I have an iterator pointing to the element at index 0:

```
*(it++) // will print element at index 0 and move the iterator forward to index 1
*(++it) // will move the iterator at index 1 and print element at index 1
*(it+1) // will print element at index 1, the iterator does not "move"
```

You can see this in action [here](https://ideone.com/2tx8jj).

Answer (score 0):

`it++` means "increase it, and return the value of it before it was increased". That's just the semantics of the postfix `++` operator. (It behaves the same for integers). It doesn't work in `*(it+1)` because now you're not increasing the iterator, but only looking at the next value. `(it+1)` doesn't change `it` at all, whereas it++ or ++it does.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
  int a = 0;
  std::cout << (a++) << "\n"; // Postfix ++, that you used. Prints 0
  std::cout << a << "\n";     // but now a is 1.
  std::cout << (++a) << "\n"; // Prefix ++, increases a and returns the increased value => Prints 2
  std::cout << a << "\n";     // Prints 2
}
```

Ideone link: http://ideone.com/QvkdlX

And yes, your increasing your iterator twice, once in the loop and once when you print it. Do you really want that?

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing the iterator in you print "cout<<*it++;". I would just print it like this "cout<<*it;" and increment the iterator with prefix notation "++it" in your for-loop. Since iterators are large and hold various data relating to the container, this will save the computer from having to store the iterator until the next line executes.